# SharePoint 2013 Scaling out downtime

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I want to add 3 web application and one WFE server to our SharePoint 2013 environment then I want to dedicate one web application to search and one to Log binder and one for the other services.

I just want to know does this project need any downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a server into does not required the down time at all. Because all the operations will be performed on the new server. But when it comes to configuring the services on server then may be you see the some down time.

- when you change the search topology this may cause the search outage but not farm outage.
- if you adding another WFE and using the loadbalancr then it is fine but if you moving all web applications to new WFE then it will cause a hiccup for the web apps.

[Adding a SharePoint 2013 Server To A Farm](https://miteshc.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/adding-a-sharepoint-2013-server-to-a-farm/)